# Determine whether $(-1, 2) \cup [3, \infty)$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I want to determine whether the set $(-1, 2) \cup [3, \infty)$ is open. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the definition, but here is my attempt at the problem... Please let me know if this is okay thanks!

Claim: $(-1, 2) \cup [3, \infty)$ is not open.

Let $x = 3 \in (-1, 2) \cup [3, \infty)$, then for any $h > 0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
3 - h < 3
\end{equation*}
which implies that $(3 - h , 3 + h)$ includes elements that are also in $(2, 3)$, so
\begin{equation*}
(3 - h , 3 + h) \not\subset (-1, 2) \cup [3, \infty).
\end{equation*}
The set is not open.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Open in where? Do you mean open in $\Bbb R$ with usual topology? If my latter assumption is the thing you mentioned then you are right. Here $3$ is in the set which is not an interior point.

Comment: @Anacardium Yea open in $\mathbb{R}$, the definition of open I have been given is: "Let A $\subset\mathbb{R}$. If $\forall x\in A, \exists h\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $(x-h, x+h)\subset A$, then $A$ is open.